# Call to undefined function issets() con php y mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un proyecto escolar por lo que no sé casi nada de código. Me aparece

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function issets() in C:\Users\jhon\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\chevesic\vista\pages\shop-single.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\jhon\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\chevesic\vista\pages\shop-single.php on line 3

con el código al inicio de la página

```
include("../../controlador/conexionBD.php");
if (issets ($GET['id'])){
$resultado = $conexion ->query("select * from productos  where id=".$_GET['id'])or die($conexion->$error);
 if(mysqli_num_rows ($resultado) > 0 ){
  $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

}else{
   
    header("Location: gallery.php");
}
}else{
 //redireccionar
header("Location: gallery.php");
}
?>
```

No sé qué haya hecho mal porque estoy siguiendo paso a paso un vídeo para realizar un carrito de compras, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tienes un typo, la función se llama [**`isset()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) sin la **s** que pusiste al final, te comento que eso sería motivo de cierre de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Camila, en tu código debes usar la función isset() y sin espacio, adicional debes colocar el simbolo de guion al piso en el $_GET, debes corregir en la linea de tu código para que quede de la siguiente manera.

if (isset($_GET['id']))

Comment: Consejo: evitemos responder a preguntas cuya solución proviene de corregir un typo pues terminan cerradas